# Convert date format in file names to yyyy-mm-dd (ISO Format) - Currently in multiple other formats, including yyyy.mm.dd, mm.dd.yyyy, and mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: regex, powershell, date

I have a file system that has files at various folder levels with the date in the filename in the wrong date format.

I'm looking to use powershell to go through and update them to the correct date format (ISO Date).

This is what I have figured out so far (for switching yyyy.mm.dd to yyyy-mm-dd), but it's not quite right:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | % { Rename-Item -Path $_.PSPath -NewName $_.Name.replace("201[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[ -~].","201[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[ -~].")}
```

The following script is successful in changing dots to dashes, but it changes all dots to dashes, and I want to be careful not to change any dots after the 10th character, and only on files that match the formatting mentioned (e.g. 201[0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]).

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $_.PSPath -Filter "*.pdf" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Replace(".","-") + $_.Extension }
```

I know I'm getting close with that first one, but I'm not quite there. Does anyone have any suggestions for changes to make to it?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the naming convention?  You could be more granular and split on specific characters to get your date alone.

Answer (score 0):

When working with dates I suggest parsing them into datetime objects so you can take advantage of the built in features.

Since you are working with a number of formats where the days and months are easily transposed, I suggest individual finely tuned filters. You could also use a switch and match on basename. Edit: I rewrote using a switch instead.

You can also use `-WhatIf` to confirm that the rename-item works properly.

```
Get-ChildItem -path $path -recurse -include *.pdf | Where-Object BaseName -match ".*[\d\.\-]{10}$" | Foreach-Object { 
    $null = $PSItem.BaseName -match "(.*)([\d\.\-]{10})$"
    Switch -regex ($matches[2]){
        "\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}" {$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[2],"yyyy-dd-MM",$null)}
        "\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}" {$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[2],"MM.dd.yyyy",$null)}
        "\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}" {$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[2],"yyyy.dd.MM",$null)}
    }

    $PSItem | rename-Item -NewName "$(Matches[1]).($date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")$($PSItem.Extenstion))"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with a regex. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '(.*)(\d{4})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})(.*)') {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Name -replace '(.*)(\d{4})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})(.*)','$1$2-$3-$4$5') -Whatif
        }
    }
```